# How to give a default value to a generic parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function :

```
function demo<T>(init: T) {
    return init;
}
```

I would like to give `init` the default value `{}` when omitted. So I wrote :

```
function demo2<T>(init: T = {}) {
    return init;
}
```

But of course, this gives me the error :

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.(2322)
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYFs4B4AqA%20AChjBigC5EcBKRAbwFgAoRFxAJ1ShDaWNIG4mAXyZNQkWAhQY4AJlyE%205SogC8dITQbNWHLj0RLBjEYyZA).

How could I force `T` to be `{}` when the parameter is omitted ? Thank you.

Comment: you cannot guarantee that extended type also would be a partial. `interface Derived extends Partial<ListVariables>{
  bbb: string;
}
`. Try to pass a variable of this type.

Comment: @Anatoly Yes but is there a way to automatically affect the empty object type to `T` when the parameter is omitted ?

Comment: How? If you use `useListVariables<Derived>` then you cannot use `{}` as a default value

Comment: Could you edit this code to be a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?  Before I post answers I like to be able to test them against the example use case, but I don't know what `ListVariables` is, nor am I positive what results you want to see for different uses of `useListVariables()` (e.g., what if someone manually specifies the type parameter vs letting the compiler infer it).  Any code that shows what you tried.  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz It's done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is technically correct; the *callers* of your `demo2()` function is allowed to specify the type parameter `T` to be whatever they want it to be.  This means a call like the following will not result in a compiler error, yet will easily lead to a runtime error:

```
const z2 = demo2<{ a: number }>(); // uh oh, no error 
z2.a.toFixed(); // no error at compile time but "z2.a is undefined" at runtime
```

Still, if you think the likelihood of someone doing that (manually specifying a generic type parameter) is low, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error, while at the same time using a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that the compiler will infer `{}` for `T` when you leave out the `init` property:

```
// assertion with default type parameter
function demo3<T = {}>(init: T = {} as T) {
    return init;
}
```

This gives you the following desirable behavior:

```
const x3 = demo3(); // {}
const y3 = demo3({ a: 123 }); // {a: number}
```

while still allowing the following undesirable behavior:

```
const z3 = demo3<{ a: number }>(); // no compiler error
z3.a.toFixed(); // RUNTIME ERROR!
```

---

If you want to prohibit manually specifying `T` without passing in a value of type `T`, you might consider using something like an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) with multiple call signatures:

// overload

```
function demo4(): {};
function demo4<T>(init: T): T;
function demo4(init = {}) {
    return init;
}
```

Here, if a caller leaves out the `init` parameter, the function is no longer treated as generic; the return type is just `{}`.  On the other hand, if the caller provides an `init` parameter, then the function is treated just like your original `demo()` function.  The implementation of the function works for either call signature.

This also results in the desirable behavior for "normal" calls:

```
const x4 = demo4(); // {}
const y4 = demo4({ a: 123 }); // {a: number}
```

And also gives a compiler warning if someone tries to call it the wrong way:

```
const z4 = demo4<{ a: number }>(); // compiler error! an argument for init is required
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYFs4B4AqA+AChjBigC5EcBKRAbwFgAoRFxAJ1ShDaWNIG4mAXyZNQkWAhQY4AJlyE+5SogC8dITQbNWHLj0RLBjEYwgIAzlEQAvWWumZ5tRAEMKYEOgBGqNoiFCKn5EAHpQxBAAC0Q4KIAaRDA4RD82OH8mOwA6V2yoOAAxGAAPVGQCYLCI5NS2dP9Xa3N0AAcYABtURFh0bu8QawAiGwAWXMMLSLA0YGJyobdrNnBe1FFGJnC3Cws-SSQAd1IY2dcQDusoAE9W7tbXNlc+qD8xcGh4JDRMAGZcBy0QJEEjKHCAoQ7ShaJisdicbi8UHGUzmMBWRAlX4OH5wX6VELbIFMNEY67Y9S4-EudyIACMsmxmkJEVotM8Pj8qMs1hsFMceKwNI8Xl8-mBVW20ViCSSKTSGUQWV+uXyRVK5QJ1TldQaS0QLXaXR6MD6iAGwz5ExgU3As3myEWTXYq1N602jG2cAAbn4OnBXMh3hIvgLRpUKEDjOJPlJcaMFCDSBRqCnox8DmGk9Z1ECYToWHpEYZkcISTzMaMcTJw5LWdz0dZrlXKTWCML6YyAnW6OzRVzy43bC2w0K3CLOeKgiyDXA2p0-LqMgBCNxIR4Acy8qDA1mAiqUk3hAEcQDAOEGPUA)