# TypeScript conditional return type using an object parameter, and default values

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function where the return type is specified by a string, but with a few extra twists thrown in:

- The parameter is in an object
- The parameter is optional
- The object is optional

Can this be done?

Here's a stripped down version of what I'm trying to do. In the examples below, I show the different ways I want to be able to call my function `fn()` and have TypeScript correctly infer the return type:

```
interface NumberWrapper {
  type: "my_number";
  value: number;
}

const x1: number        = fn(1, { returnType: "bare" });
const x2: NumberWrapper = fn(1, { returnType: "wrapped" });
const x3: void          = fn(1, { returnType: "none" });
const x4: number        = fn(1, {});
const x5: number        = fn(1);
```

For `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, the function is called with a value for `returnType`.

For `x4`, no value is provided for `returnType`, and I want it to default to `"bare"`. Similarly, for `x5`, the object isn't provided at all, and I want it to behave as though `returnType` is `"bare"`.

(You might be wondering why I'm bothering to put `returnType` in an object, since it's just one parameter. In my actual use case, there are other parameters in the object.)

So far I've been able to get `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` to work, but not `x4` or `x5`. Here' what I have:

```
type ReturnMap<T extends "bare" | "wrapped" | "none"> = T extends "bare"
  ? number
  : T extends "wrapped"
  ? NumberWrapper
  : void;

function fn<T extends "bare" | "wrapped" | "none">(
  x: number,
  { returnType }: { returnType: T }
): ReturnMap<T> {
  if (returnType === "bare") {
    return x as ReturnMap<T>;
  } else if (returnType === "wrapped") {
    return { type: "my_number", value: x } as ReturnMap<T>;
  } else {
    return undefined as ReturnMap<T>;
  }
}
```

One thing I dislike is that each `return` statement has the form `return x as ReturnMap<T>` at the end. I'd like to not do that because the `as` causes it to lose some type safety.

But the bigger problem is that this doesn't work for `x4` and `x5`. I've tried using default values in different ways, but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Instead of specifying return type in the object, could you not create 3 different types to represent bare/wrapped/none since there are other parameters there and you can avoid having a 'returnType' field?

Comment: You will always have some type safety guarantee issue inside the implementation, unfortunately, so some amount of type assertion or overload loosening will be necessary.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVZ95N) meet your needs?   If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That's pretty good! The only thing I wish was different is that I'd prefer to not construct the object with all the possible return types and then only use one of them. For my specific use case, that won't introduce too much overhead, but for other cases, it could be significant performance penalty -- for example, if the different return types require different computations.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mp92BW) work better for you, then?

Comment: @jcalz That looks better for sure.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix is to make the generic type the *whole argument* rather than only the `returnType` property. Then it's just a (longer) conditional operator chain to get the types you want - though this still requires the ugly `as` assertions.

```
type Arg = undefined | { returnType?: "bare" | "wrapped" | "none" };
type ReturnMap<T extends Arg> =
  T extends { returnType: 'wrapped' }
    ? NumberWrapper
    : T extends { returnType: 'none' }
      ? void
      : number;

function fn<T extends Arg>(
  x: number,
  arg?: T
): ReturnMap<T> {
  if (!arg || !('returnType' in arg) || arg.returnType === 'bare') {
    return x as ReturnMap<T>;
  } else if (arg.returnType === 'wrapped') {
    return { type: "my_number", value: x } as ReturnMap<T>;
  } else {
    return undefined as ReturnMap<T>;
  }
}

const x1: number = fn(1, { returnType: "bare" });
const x2: NumberWrapper = fn(1, { returnType: "wrapped" });
const x3: void = fn(1, { returnType: "none" });
const x4: number = fn(1, {});
const x5: number = fn(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd probably write your `fn()` function:

```
interface ReturnMap {
  bare: number,
  wrapped: NumberWrapper,
  none: void
}

function fn<K extends keyof ReturnMap = "bare">(
  x: number,
  { returnType = "bare" as K }: { returnType?: K } = { returnType: "bare" as K }
): ReturnMap[K] {
  return {
    get bare() { return x },
    get wrapped() { return { type: "my_number" as const, value: x } },
    get none() { return undefined }
  }[returnType]

}
```

Explanations:

---

For your "`as ReturnMap<T>`" issue, the problem is that the compiler cannot verify that your implementation satisfies the return type.  The type `ReturnMap<T>` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on a generic type parameter `T`.  In such cases the compiler says "I don't know what `T` is so I don't know what `ReturnMap<T>` it.  Your implementation tests `arg`, but the compiler cannot use those tests to narrow the type parameter `T`.  This is a known missing feature in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for more information.

I'd generally recommend refactoring to something the compiler can understand, such as [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) an object using a generic key.

That's why `ReturnMap` is an actual mapping type with keys corresponding to your `returnType` values, and whose property values are the associated return types.  Then `fn()` can be generic in `K extends keyof ReturnMap` and you will return `ReturnMap[K]` by looking up the `returnType` property of an object of type `ReturnMap`

Note that I've used [getter methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) so that the object of type `ReturnMap` doesn't have to pre-compute the result for every possible input.

---

For the "default" issue with the`x4` and `x5` cases, you want the behavior you get from the following JavaScript using both a [function parameter default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) and a [destructuring assignment default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_values_2):

```
function fn(x, {returnType = "bare"} = {returnType: "bare"}) {}
```

That has exactly the runtime behavior you're looking for.  Unfortunately when you give it typings, you'll need some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler to accept it.  That's because [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and default parameters don't really play very nicely together in TypeScript.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64359115/2887218) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65221629/2887218) for more information.

The defaults are handled by giving `K` a [default type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `"bare"`; so if the compiler cannot infer `K` from your call to `fn()`, it will fall back to `"bare"`.  Similarly we make the `returnType` variable default to `"bare"` inside the implementation via the JavaScript destructuring assignment default and the function parameter default...

...but the compiler can't see that these defaults will happen together.  That's why we use type assertions.  By writing `"bare" as K` I'm saying that, in the cases where we use the default for `returnType`, then we will also be using the default for `K`.  It's technically possible that someone could write `fn<"none">(1)`, and in that case things would break. But probably nobody will do that, so we can just assume that `K` will be `"bare"` when defaults are used.

---

And there you go.  It has the desired results:

```
const x1: number = fn(1, { returnType: "bare" });
const x2: NumberWrapper = fn(1, { returnType: "wrapped" });
const x3: void = fn(1, { returnType: "none" });
const x4: number = fn(1, {});
const x5: number = fn(1);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2AjaB1KOAByOmQG8BYAKGWTAE9SAuZAIkwYH0Qtco2Abhp0AbnAA26CK145ow6gF8aNBAHsQAZzDIAHgEZZfMgF5kMEAAoDAGgrIoEMOiggAKkxntscJ22QlAEpFDW1dPQAmVgx5KAJiUihkc0sbe3JHZ1cPL1Y2AHdCEggAEwDg0M0dfQBmVlF1YFKUi2s7BycXN08WdhBNCAqQtWqIgBZjONa0jvJK0fD9AFYp-hn2keoaUEhYRBQAJWy3AFliChFkXyc16FsrosSymJN44qSH2mQBkG9G5o0FTbagAelBFnQIAQYGAmjaVj0GS6OV6KHMbBuQyUrXIKJ6eR8fmxQQowJoMChMLhIDaAB4ANLICB6SAgUpaZAAawgDHUMGQx26IHORFamOJbAAfFYrno7lAvnRMvjcqRxViAnBOUylKwVSc1RAAPysXW4rLCtH5TXIbXIXU0IKsIU5UUAbQZAF1Lt9Vb66HQAObOa7Eqykg3C-SBJWBkO6J4lUoRzqGhyMPocbhyfhazlhHT2cRSbx6QKxq7B0O-CCpqM5ZBQ0oQGCgMqBK5Kd2qtFe1TKGhAA)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful, especially the explanations of why TypeScript behaves the way it does.