# How to deal with TypeScript not treating uninitialized optional parameter as undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the simplified reproduction of my function:

```js
const nullify = <T extends string | undefined>(
  value?: T,
): T extends string ? string : null => {
  if (value === undefined) return null as any;
  return value as any;
};
```

What I expect from these function typings is to treat lack of `value` as `undefined`, but TypeScript doesn't allow this, and instead it returns a union `string | null`. The only way to get `null` from this function is to explicitly pass `undefined`.

```js
const result1 = nullify('string');  // result1 is string, as expected
const result2 = nullify(undefined); // result2 is null, as expected
const result3 = nullify();          // result3 is (string | null), but should be just null
```

Is there an idiomatic way to deal with this?

Comment: What is `Type1` and `Type2`?  Ideally your code would be a [mre] that can be pasted into a standalone IDE to enable people to get right to work fixing the relevant issue, instead of first fixing unrelated issues just to reproduce the relevant issue.

Comment: Agree with jcalz. I have it working on my end, but I had to change things around. Please provide more code so we can run what you are running.

Comment: To be specific, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4zJw) is the fix (generic parameter default) but there are other errors you need to fix first.  Debug the example code until the only problem that remains is the one you want help with, and then someone can post something about generic parameter defaults.

Comment: @jcalz Your fix helped, I never saw this feature of TS before, thank you a lot. I also refactored my example to be minimally reproducible

Comment: You might want to use overloading here instead of generics. Also `return null as any` when the function is declared to return a `string` looks like a very bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you don't pass in a `value` argument, there is no value from which the compiler can infer `T`, and inference just fails.  When inference fails, it generally falls back to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which in your case is `string | undefined`.  If you want to change what it falls back to, you can set a [generic parameter *default*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) using `=` syntax:

```
const nullify = <T extends string | undefined = undefined>( 
//                      default generic ----> ^^^^^^^^^^^
    value?: T,
): T extends string ? string : null => {
    if (value === undefined) return null as any;
    return value as any;
};
```

And you'll only see a difference when you leave `value` out:

```
const result1 = nullify('string');  // string, as expected
const result2 = nullify(undefined); // null, as expected
const result3 = nullify();  // null, as expected
```

Hooray!

---

There is the drawback that technically the caller can specify any value of `T` that they want.  So nothing stops a particularly unhinged caller from doing this:

```
const oops = nullify<string>(); // string, oops
// ---------------> ^^^^^^^^ <--- manually specify string
```

Since `string` is manually specified for `T`, and the `value` parameter is optional, there is no compiler error.  And now you have a situation where the compiler mistakenly thinks a `null` value is of type `string`.

This is probably not very likely to happen, so you could just leave it alone and not worry about it.  TypeScript is actually [unsound in quite a few places](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) so you wouldn't really be making things any worse here.

Still, if you care about such things, then you need to refactor.  One way is to make your generic type parameter correspond to the [tuple type of a rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types):

```
const nullify = <T extends [string] | [undefined?]>(
    ...[value]: T
): T extends [string] ? string : null => {
    if (value === undefined) return null as any;
    return value as any;
};

const result1 = nullify('string');  // string, as expected
const result2 = nullify(undefined); // null, as expected
const result3 = nullify();  // null, as expected
```

Now you cannot easily pass something incorrect, since the only acceptable situation in which `value` is missing or `undefined` is when `T` extends `[undefined?]`:

```
const okayNow = nullify<[string]>(); // error, as expected
```

The traditional way of doing this sort of thing is to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead of (or alongside) generics, but instead of going into this, I'll just point interested parties to [How to give a default value to a generic parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65221629/2887218) for more information.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlAlmGAbCARCAZiAK5YAuSA3gFBJ1LwD2wUFwpWaBAnkgLxIAPABUkEAB5kIwACZQkrAE5pgAcyQAfJMVmEVEGf226C+mQD4AFLXq2AbiCzEIAfgBcSYQBobdAJQeohJSsvJKKuouCmTKakge7FhY-OZUvrZIXEiWDk7IfAXGMnrABn5IihBkxIrASInJIPIgwNwA3Om2ldW1SLnOSE2DrR22AL4d6UwsFJVQpGQAjEYNXNyWAOThaht+bXQA9AfRsapeg-ISMBDwUjJTzKwV0AsATCsca5Y6xaalMnskEd6hxzkMrjc7g8Zs95uQAMwfJJfQFA44NMGXcTXW4GajQp6MRgweQCVY8QTbVRWQHAqnnIkk-FjfGgSCwBDIAAKIEU4HkNFs0ye5N4AhEYkk0jkSAA2lSALqaOU-EoGFwKqydegAOj1sv6EAVgXSAU8kpCMvlMQiSqiVPiIKSKTSGXoWRyjgGBQEqr+ZWePTqDQuw3a2ro3RqdUNoZa4fGkyFj1mL3IyzJnx4mypu32aJOEUxkpxUOTMLmbyRnGzfrMtPRoNDENx93LT0rCOrKPzwIxzexkLxBIojAA1iBuAA5RgAd27FOtp01lgbYkUikYil8zPxQA)

Answer (score -1):

Try checking if value is string instead.

```js
const nullify = <T extends string | undefined>(
  value?: T,
): T extends string ? string : null => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') return value as any;
  return null as any;
};
```

Comment: The problem is not the implementation, but the type declaration - a call `nullify()` without arguments is inferred to return `string | null` but the OP wants `null`.