# TS function with dynamic keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In the following Javascript code, I calculate `id` and `name` based on dynamic `nameField` and `idField` arguments, it's a minimal example of a complex function, How can I convert it to Typescript and ask TS to ensure that `option` has `nameField` and `idField` fields?

`name` is `string` and `id` is `number`

```js
export const foo =
  (
    option,
    nameField = 'name',
    idField = 'id',
  ) => {
    const name = option[nameField];
    const id = option[idField];
    const result =  { id, name };
    /// ... other codes
  }
```

My best effort

```
export const foo = <T extends Record<string, any>>(
  option: T,
  nameField: keyof T = 'name' as keyof T,
  idField: keyof T = 'id' as keyof T,
) => {
  const name = option[nameField];
  const id = option[idField];
  const result =  { id, name };
  /// ... other codes
};
```

I expect error in the following code

```
const option = {
  id: '1', // Should be number
  name: 'Foo'
  value: 2
};

const a = foo(option);  // Error here
const b = foo(option,'name','value');  // OK
```

Comment: You seem to know it needs generics. What effort have you made to solve it?

Comment: If I define generic type `T` and make `option:T` and then I can set `nameField = 'name' as keyof T` but I have some problem to enfoce name is string and id is number

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: I expect error, Updated question for clarification

Comment: you typed the values to be `any`

Comment: Yes, I don't know how can I conditionally set it based on function argument

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863875/typescript-how-do-you-filter-a-types-properties-to-those-of-a-certain-type

Comment: consider that it depends on argument!!

Comment: Oof, rather icky: https://tsplay.dev/wgK7Mw

Comment: WOW! so complecated!

Comment: Well, there's [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Wkl79w) which is more straightforward but might not give as intuitive errors when you do something wrong.  If that meets your needs then I'll write up an answer explaining; let me know.

Comment: I'll ask more explicitly: Does [my suggestion](https://tsplay.dev/Wkl79w) meet your needs? If so I will write up an actual answer (and not just a comment).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it is. Kindly in your answer explain why do we need `PropertyKey = 'name'`

Comment: Just a problem if you change `id` to a number, it dosen't works

Comment: Okay try [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mZJ7om) (I had to block inference).  Let me know if you want to see that written up (and please test thoroughly before giving me a yes or no, so I don't write an answer that actually fails to work for a use case you care about)

Comment: It's perfect! works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can take is to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `N` of `nameField` and the type `I` of `idField`, and then make `option` be of a type known to have a `string` property at key `N` and a `number` property at key `I`.  That would imply a call signature like

```
const foo = <N extends PropertyKey, I extends PropertyKey>(
  option: Record<N, string> & Record<I, number>,
  nameField: N, 
  idField: I
) => {};
```

The [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) refers to an object with properties of type `V` at keys of type `K`, and the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) combines both types.  So `Record<N, string> & Record<I, number>` means "a type with a `string` property at key `N` and a `number` property at key `I`".

---

Okay, but you want `nameField` and `idField` to be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) and default to `"name"` and `"id"`, respectively, if no arguments are provided by the caller.  That doesn't play very nicely with generics, since there's no way to know that `N` or `I` (chosen by the caller) will actually be `"name"` or `"id"` (chosen by the implementation) in such a case.  See [How to give a default value to a generic parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65221629/2887218) and [microsoft/TypeScript#49158](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49158).  One workaround mentioned in both places is to give `N` and `I` [default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) in case the arguments for `nameField` and `idField` are not provided, and then just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `"name"` and `"id"` are of types `N` and `I`.  That looks like:

```
const foo = <
  N extends PropertyKey = "name", 
  I extends PropertyKey = "id"
>(
  option: Record<N, string> & Record<I, number>,
  nameField = 'name' as N, 
  idField = 'id' as I
) => {};
```

---

That's close to what we want, except that some vagaries of generic type inference will cause `N` and `I` to be inferred from `option` if `nameField` and `idField` are left out.  But we really don't want that behavior; `N` and `I` should be inferred from `nameField` and `idField`, or default to `"name"` and `"id"`... and `option` should only be *checked*.  That means the `N` and `I` inside `Record<N, string> & Record<I, number>` should be *non-inferential type parameter usages* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  There's no native `NoInfer` to use here, so we can't write `Record<NoInfer<N>, string> & Record<NoInfer<I>, number>` without implementing `NoInfer` ourselves.  One technique mentioned in that GitHub issue is to intersect with the empty object type, like `type NoInfer<T> = T & {}`, which lowers the inference priority.  Let's do that here:

```
const foo = <
  N extends PropertyKey = 'name',
  I extends PropertyKey = 'id'
>(
  option: Record<N & {}, string> & Record<I & {}, number>,
  nameField = 'name' as N,
  idField = 'id' as I,
) => {
  const name: string = option[nameField];
  const id: number = option[idField];
  const result = { id, name };
  console.log(id.toFixed())
};
```

That's our final form.

---

Let's test it:

```
const option = {
  id: '2',
  name: 'Foo',
  value: 2
};

const a = foo(option);  // Error here
const b = foo(option, 'name', 'value');  // okay

const c = foo({ name: "abc", id: 123 }); // okay
const d = foo({ name: "abc", id: "123" }); // error
```

That all behaves as desired.  Note that the workaround to generic defaults does have the potential failure mode where the caller manually specifies the `N` and `I` type arguments while also not passing in the `nameField` and `idField` arguments:

```
foo<"name", "value">(option); // no compiler error!
```

That's quite unlikely, but you should be aware of it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8BYAUDGA5GAUwA8pCwATCGABQCcQAHQuqATwGlC2UYByMAEMAtoT4AabLgCSRUuSq0GzVp268+ASwp9sAPgAUUmEyibwALhgAlQqDoU0BAGQwA3gF9xMaHU1gAcz0YV1t7R1lXT28wAFdhACMWPUkcGCFRADFNQgAbCg0MsRhBajxU3G1svILULR0S6mlUgEoUYLdjUEhYIqtffwDeU3MwAG0i6vyAXQBuLvBoGG0rOMSWYcYzcDGqnJn5tO6lukIIWNzYVDdlihiRQhgPQ9xjkFzCADpckACDbU+UBA2WIhAoBhaLWwz2wsKwx1gI3AvE6aRW-AATBJjH1+JlENi0gA3QS5WKEKwY6GHbBQOg8VGvRawQS8BAgAxIsAtWa4AD0fJgAFE6Aw6DAABYsQjQmDAQRQYASmAGQhtRlyxbvL4-P5qw4ebAImAJNmITlbUbeAQPCT8ElksQ8-mCkAAa0EbDhxuAZo5N1xACJBAlgIHvOiAIwYgDMT2dApMHq98OZMFq8HNAYeVmDofDt1z0ZjgfjvMTLDF3rTjBAZDAZlJ0gg50eqHZaEDRQLgYd5MDhi5CcFYCQoGEjE0H3FlZA4oSsRZwCgsVJyxb5KAA)